# Is it possible to get google analytics event timestamp in bigquery?

Tags: google-analytics, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

Im trying to get a the event timestamp from big query (google analytics 360) but I cant seem to find the correct export field to get it.

I have tried `hits.eventInfo.timestamp` and `hits.eventInfo.datetime` but none of them seem to work.

My query is

```
SELECT 
    hits.eventInfo.timestamp as purchaseDate,
    fullVisitorId as visitorId
  FROM (tables)
  WHERE LOWER(hits.eventInfo.eventAction) == 'purchase'
  GROUP BY 2
  ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Answer (score 3):

#### LegacySQL

```sql
DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP(FORMAT_UTC_USEC(visitStartTime*1000000)), (hits.time/1000), "SECOND")
```

This will return `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` in UTC.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This seems to work if you're using BigQuery's standard SQL ```DATETIME_ADD(DATETIME(TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(t.visitStartTime)), INTERVAL h.time MILLISECOND)```

Answer (score 2):

There is no field for hit timestamp however you can calculate this from hits.time and visitStartTime. There is a row from [Schema description:](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en&ref_topic=3416089)

hits.time   INTEGER The number of milliseconds after the visitStartTime when this hit was registered. The first hit has a hits.time of 0